# Probability of two variable length sub-tasks completing in X amount of time

Tags: probability

I've got X seconds to complete a task. This task is comprised of two sub-tasks, sub-task #1 and sub-task #2, which take variable amounts of time and the duration of one sub-task does not affect the other.

I have information about every sub-task attempt and how long it took e.g. one attempt might take 0.5 seconds, another might take 10 seconds and there's millions of records. From this information I can work out the average and median for each of the sub-tasks, but I would really like to know the probability/percentage of both tasks completing in less than or equal to X seconds.

How would I work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the records (time length) for sub-task $\#1$ as $\{T_1[1],\,T_1[2],\,T_1[3],\ldots,\, T_1[N_1]\}~$, where $N_1$ is the amount of data you have. For example, if for sub-task $\#1$ you have $1.4$ millions records, then $N_1 = 1400000$

Do the same for sub-task $\#2$ and have $\{T_2[1],\,T_2[2],\,T_2[3],\ldots,\, T_2[N_2]\}$.

Now do pairwise addition, with the list size $N \equiv\min(N_1,\, N_2)$ being the smaller one of $N_1$ and $N_2$.
\begin{aligned}
S_1 &= T_1[1] + T_2[1] \\
S_2 &= T_1[2] + T_2[2] \\
S_3 &= T_1[3] + T_2[3] \\
&\qquad\vdots \\
S_k &= T_1[k] + T_2[k] \\
&\qquad\vdots \\
S_N &= T_1[N] + T_2[N] \\
\end{aligned}
It doesn't matter how you order the original two lists ($T_1$ and $T_2$) and how you pair them, since as you stated the two sub-tasks are independent.

Now that you have $S_k~$, which is a list of $N$ numbers, the desired empirical probability is then given by
$$\text{percentage} = \frac{ \text{number of $S_k$ smaller than $X$}}N$$

---

There are many fancy ways to do this. Judging from the way the question post is formulated, I recommend the most basic approach above.

Comment: makes sense. Cheers.